# Chapter 7 Errors, Ruby on Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

No matter what I write there I will always get these errors, I have read chapter twice, I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Here's my code at [GitHub](https://github.com/r0uder/sample_app)

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj04a.jpg) of errors.

user_controller.rb

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[user_params])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to user_url(@user)
      #Handle a successfull save
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private 
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Form

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>a
      <%= render '/shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line

```
@user = User.new(params[user_params])
```

to

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

in `UsersController`.

Everything else looks fine.

Comment: I've been trying to fix it for 2 days, you've just fixed everything in one second! Thank you so much. Book didn't explain that for some reason.